# Mysqli While loop: print variables inside html

Tags: php, html, variables

My php While loop run the query, but the results must be print inside html. In this moment I unknow the way to make this:

My php while loop

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$username=$_SESSION['Username'];

$result = mysqli_query($dbconn,"
 SELECT *
  FROM books
 WHERE username = '$Username'
");
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
?>
```

After this code there is a Html code where I want print the variables:

```
<a href="editBook.php?bookid=<?php echo $book_id; ?>&book_name=<?php echo $book_name; ?>">Edit</a>
```

In this moment the variable is empty

How to fix this?

***[Resolved] Update*** 
I have resolve my problem. This is the correct php script. Work fine:

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$username=$_SESSION['Username'];

$result = mysqli_query($dbconn,"
 SELECT *
  FROM books
 WHERE username = '$Username'
");
global $book_id, $book_name
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$book_id = row['book_id'];
$book_name = row['book_name'];
?>
```

*Outside while loop. Print variable inside Html:*

```
<?php echo $row['book_id']; ?> <br>
<?php echo $row['book_name']; ?>
```

*Close while loop and connection:*

```
<?php
}
mysqli_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: show your html code as well.

Comment: Sorry I have update the post. Read please.

Comment: you need `echo $rows['column_name'];`

Comment: 1st of all, you should *really* think about prepared statements, then, add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); on top of the page, and see what error shows up. Then, echo $rows['my_column_name_whatever_is_name_is'] and see what it returns

Comment: @OldPadawan he is not searching for an error, he is looking for a solution.

Comment: @Aloso : I've read it, but if $var is empty, it can *also* be a query problem, don't you think ? I just asked to show errors (if any) and echo a column

Comment: @Frankie is there exactly one book for each person, or should multiple `<a>`s be displayed (one for each database entry)?

Comment: @Aloso the answare is I want display multiple <a>s be displayed (one for each database entry.

Comment: @OldPadawan I have update the post. I had forgoten $username=$_SESSION['Username'];

Comment: @Frankie : see answer with prepared statement please

Comment: @Frankie The problem here is that `$username` does not equal to `$Username`; different letter case. Error reporting would have thrown a notice of it being undefined.

Comment: error reporting... I'm glad someone pointed that out too ^^

Comment: Now repeat the first record for quanbti records are present. Why?

Comment: @Frankie : what do you mean ? and doing what ? show updated code please

Comment: @OldPadawanI have resolved my problem and update my post. The solution is a global before while loop. The variable must be inside the loop block. Thanks.

Comment: global is only needed in functions. Here it is not necessary.

Comment: Your fixed solution is wrong, too.  Probably a typo relating to `$row`.

Comment: @RickJames yes, I fix. $rows to $row :)

Comment: You still need to change `<?php echo $row['book_id']; ?>` -- to, say, `<?php echo $book_id; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

with prepared statements :

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['Username'];

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include"config.inc.php";

/* connect to DB */
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$mdp", "$db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Error connecting : " . mysqli_connect_error($mysqli); }

$query = " SELECT * FROM books WHERE username=? ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$results = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($book_id, $book_name);
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
while($stmt->fetch()){
?>
<p><?php echo"$book_name"; ?> > <a href="editBook.php?bookid=<?php echo"$book_id"; ?>&book_name=<?php echo"$book_name"; ?>">Edit</a></p>
<?php
}
}
else
{ echo"[ no data ]"; }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

(Rewriting)

The real issue is:

```
while ($rows = ...) ;
```

This loops until `$rows` is `NULL`.  So there is nothing to display afterwards.

Since you are fetching the entire array in a single function call, there is no need for the loop!

```
$rows = ...;
```

But then you need to reference the first(?) row to get the desired data:

```
$row = $rows[0];
```

So, another approach is to just fetch one row, then close the fetch process.

Answer (score 0):

In your html you have to do this

```html
<a href="editBook.php?bookid=<?php echo $rows['book_id']; ?>&book_name=<?php echo $rows['book_name']; ?>">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As there might be multiple books for each user, you have to print the link inside the `while` loop, or store it in a string:

```php
<?php
include "connect.php";
$username = $_SESSION['Username'];

$result = mysqli_query($dbconn,"
    SELECT * FROM books
    WHERE username = '$Username'
");

$links = ""; // all links are stored in this string
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // I assume that the columns are called `id` and `name`
    $links .= '<a href="editBook.php?bookid='. $rows["id"] .'&book_name='. $rows["name"] .'">Edit '. $rows["name"] .'</a>';
}
?>
```

In the html code simply write

```php
<?php echo $links ?>
```

Note that you should use prepared statements instead. You should also take a look at the object oriented way to use mysqli using the `mysqli` class.

Comment: your code lacks a session_start, and all links will be stuck together, not knowing which one to edit, just a link... :/

Comment: No, my code does not lack a session start. I modified the code above which does not have a session_start either. Most likely, the session is started in `connect.php`. You're right that the links should have a more descriptive name, I corrected it.

Comment: we now lack an answer to his last comment :)